# How to align text at center view for PDF

Tags: pdf, text

I have a PDF file which has each page being actually formed from 2 pages, like this (it is not in English):[image]

I used mutool to split each page into 2 pages according to Peque's answer: [Splitting a PDF page in two](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56853/splitting-a-pdf-page-in-two) and it worked. But now the 2 pages does not align to the center but the odd pages are aligned to the left, while the even ones are aligned to the right:
[image]

How can I fix this? Please help me, thank you very much.
Here is the link of the file:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1a_jQlx0rx0Zu1ms7IiFOydiu1bGfymSU

Answer (score 0):

as per the manual page of `man mutool`

POSTER
       mutool poster [options] input.pdf [output.pdf]

```
   The poster command splits each page into tiles, and puts each tile on a
   page of its own. It's useful for printing a large page onto smaller
   pieces of paper that can then be glued together to create a large
   poster.

   -p password
          Use the specified password if the file is encrypted.

   -x factor
          Split the page into this many horizontal pieces.

   -y factor
          Split the page into this many vertical pieces.

   The output will have x times y number of pages for each input page.
```

it justs split the page width into the number of parts you mention.. it knows only the physical size of the paper/ page in x and y direction and splits.. it does nothing nor it does know anything about the text content it it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yeah, guess I will just have to live with it. Thanks anyway.